# Single SWF file for Flex 4 created apps?

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications, flex4, flash

I made an application in Flex 4. When I export a release build, it generates a whole bunch of files. (including the skins used, etc, etc.)

How do I make those plentiful files **except** the container HTML file, get compiled into a single SWF file?

E.g.,
My folder should only contain:

- my_app.swf
- my_app.html

But my_app.swf should still run like a normal Flex 4 app, only this time, all the files, images, skins, etc are inside that one SWF file.

Thanks to those who'd help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your project in Flash Builder, go to:

*Project->Properties*

than

*Flex Build Path->Library Path*

and finally change the dropdown named *"Framework linkage*" to "Merged into code".

Recompile :)

Comment: That did the trick about the skins, however, the images seem to still stay outside the swf file...

Comment: The comment below is a good answer to the images issue. As a side note - there are problems with having a lot of embedded stuff which sometimes causes the compilation to take a very long time.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to embed images in flex.For that refer http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html.

That done, you will not need assets like images and sound files in the folder.They will already be embedded in your swf.
NOTE:This will increase the size of you swf drastically.